# Does information passes to a new table via CREATE TABLE update itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table TABLE1 which is updated daily via an app. I would like to create another table TABLE2, based on TABLE 1 using the CREATE TABLE function. Will TABLE2 update as new rows are added to table1?

Comment: No.  I think you might want a view.

Comment: Can a view be queried?

Comment: Yes, it can be queried. To answer your actual question - no, create another table will not automatically cause rows in the other table to appear in your new table. However, this sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you might find a better path by asking about your goal and not your chosen path to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table 2 will not receive the rows from Table 1. By creating Table 2 off of Table 1's schema, you're just creating an empty table.

Depending on what you need to use Table 2 for, you might want to consider making a View off of Table 1, or otherwise if you need Table 2 to be its own thing, create a Trigger after INSERT on Table 1.